# Working with extra large numbers in C++ only using standard library (without boost Multiprecision or gmp)

Tags: c++, stl, largenumber

I have a task to work with extra large numbers on our scientific project. Numbers are between 150 and 200 digits. 
How can I accomplish this only using the standard template library?
I am ok on lower values using long double.

I read somewhere that I should put my numbers in

Comment: why would you want to avoid proven implementations which do what you neeed?

Comment: One can only assume OP doesn't have a choice. In that case, the only real option is to reimplement the necessary classes. I would work on convincing whoever is preventing me from using libraries to be smarter.

Comment: Do you want a toy, or something with real world performance?

Comment: @Ron: One has several other options than "assume OP doesn't have a choice". e.g. assuming this is an XY problem (with Y being "avoid using STL") until the OP clarifies otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from your question that you need to work with the exact value of large integers.

Alas, the C++ standard library does not feature multiprecision arithmetic. (nor does the ancient standard template library)

From what little information you've given, your only *reasonable* option is to use an external library. It is almost certainly far more worth your effort to make that work than to try and write your own library.